# configuring database config for live site in codeigniter keep getting 500 internal server error

Tags: sql, database, model, codeigniter-2, configuration-files

Im pretty done new to actually setting up sites as a live version, I've only done websites using local host. Im using codeigniter for this one, and i've traced my problem to the model where it loads the database. This makes me think that my database config isn't set up correctly. 
The model's function is as follows:

```
public function register($email, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $gender, $birthday){

    $salt = $this->generateSalt();

    $password = $this->hash($password, $salt);

    $data = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'salt' => $salt, 'first_name' => $first_name,
        "last_name" => $last_name, 'gender' => $gender, "birthday" => $birthday);

    $this->load->database();
    if($this->db->insert('users', $data)){
        $this->loginById($this->db->insert_id());
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the database config looks like this though I removed the password and username for privacy the username and pass I used are the same as I used to get into phpmyadmin though:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'http://130.184.99.114/',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'meetings',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

So, how do I need to set this up? I think Im on the right track, but im really new to this, so please explain it in a way I can learn please! :D IF you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Your host name should not include `http://` or `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname you have listed is incorrect.

It should either be:

`'hostname' => '130.184.99.114',`

or

`'hostname' => 'localhost',`

depending on how the server has been set up.

Have you set this up in the /application/config/database.php file, or are you doing it differently? I ask as I see `failover => array()` in there, which isn't in the default configuration file.